# Javascript Calculator - Reset text input on calculator to be blank when corresponding text input is also blank

Tags: javascript, html, forms, calculator

I have a simple calculator that changes on input to convert US Dollars to Viet Nam Dong. It works just fine except for the fact that after a number is input and then removed via backspace, a "0.00" remains in the box that the calculation was performed in. I would like for the box to be blank when the other box is blank after removing a number.

Here is my Javascript:

```
function vndCalc() {
var cusd = document.getElementById("usd").value;
var cvnd = document.getElementById("vnd");
var calc = cusd * 22477.50;

cvnd.value = calc.toFixed(2);
}

function usdCalc() {
 var cusd = document.getElementById("usd");
 var cvnd = document.getElementById("vnd").value;
 var calc = cvnd / 22477.50;

 cusd.value = calc.toFixed(2);
}
```

Here is the HTML as well:

```
<fieldset id=calculator>
    <legend>USD to VND Calculator</legend> 
    <label>US Dollars:<input type="text" id="usd" oninput="vndCalc()"/></label>
    <label>VN Dongs:<input type="text" id="vnd" oninput="usdCalc()"/></label>
</fieldset>
```

I tried playing around with "if" functions, but I couldn't get anything to work. Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can control the other input with a conditional. For instance, you can try this:

```js
function usdCalc() {
 var cusd = document.getElementById("usd");
 var cvnd = document.getElementById("vnd").value;
 var calc = cvnd / 22477.50;
 
 if (cvnd == ''){
  cusd.value = '';
 } else {
  cusd.value = calc.toFixed(2); 
 }
}
```

Comment: This works great, I added the conditional to both functions while swapping variable names. I was trying to do something like this myself but couldn't get it right, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the input field == "" and set the output field to be the same

http://jsfiddle.net/40p9b2fu/

From USD

```
cvnd.value = cusd == "" ? "" : calc.toFixed(2);
```

And to USD

```
cusd.value = cvnd == "" ? "" : calc.toFixed(2);
```

If you don't like the ternary form you can do

From USD

```
if (cusd == "") {
    cvnd.value = "";
} else {
    cvnd.value = calc.toFixed(2);
}
```

and to USD

```
if (cvnd == "") {
    cusd.value = "";
} else {
    cusd.value = calc.toFixed(2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would personally add 2 buttons to trigger the conversion. [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cvgakL5r/2/).
Example:

```
var exchangeRate = 22477.50,
    usdSelector = $('#usd'),
    vndSelector = $('#vnd');

$('#convert1').click(function(){
    vndSelector.val(usdSelector.val() * exchangeRate);
})

$('#convert2').click(function(){
    usdSelector.val(vndSelector.val() / exchangeRate);
})

$('#clear').click(function(){
    usdSelector.val("");
    vndSelector.val("");
})
```

And Html:

```
<fieldset id="calculator">
    <legend>USD to VND Calculator</legend> 
    <label>US Dollars: <input type="text" id="usd"/></label>
    <label>VN Dongs: <input type="text" id="vnd"/></label>
    </br>
    <button id="convert1">Convert Dollars to Dongs</button>
    <button id="convert2">Convert Dongs to Dollars</button>
    <button id="clear">Clear</button>
</fieldset>
```